# How to find the matched SIFT features that are spatially consistent?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, feature-extraction, sift

I have extracted **DenseSIFT** from the query and database image and quantized by `kmeans` using `VLFeat`. The challenge is to find those SIFT features that quantized to the same visual words and be spatially consistent (have a similar position to object centers). I have tried few techniques:

1. using FLANN() on the SIFT (normal SIFT) coordinates on both query and database image and find the nearest neighbor and then comparing the visual words (NOTE: this gave few points that did not work).
2. Using [Coherent-Point-Drift (CPD)](https://github.com/siavashk/pycpd) on SIFT coordinates to find the matched points (I am not sure about this whether it is a right solution or not).

I am struggling with it for many days, and I hope experts can guide me with this. What are the possible solutions or algorithms that I can use for solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of those two methods you mentioned achieve what you want do. The answer depends on the object in your pictures. If it has mostly flat faces, then you can rely on estimating the homography, see [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html).

[image]

If that's not case then can use the epipolar constraint to remove outliers / get geometrically consistent matches, see [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/de9/tutorial_py_epipolar_geometry.html). There are some other ways to achieve this if the speed is of importance in your application.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me, I will try the solution that you suggested and update it here